# Increase Import jobs limit

Tags: google-bigquery

Please suggest me how we can increase no of import jobs  from default limit (1000) to x number per table per day.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is 1000 per table per day to encourage people to batch their imports into larger chunks. Lots of tiny imports adds overhead to BigQuery, which is why we encourage bigger imports. We may give quota exceptions when the amount of data being imported is huge, however.

If you give more details about how you are importing your data and expected daily import sizes, we can evaluate your request. If it is just so that you can add a few rows at a time at a high frequency, we'll be unlikely to grant the quota exception.

Comment: Thank you Jordan! We wanted to push the data to BigQuery  frequently(3 mins). So that data is  available for analysis in very short period of time.

Comment: 3 minutes should be doable without a quota exception -- that would be 480 imports per table per day.

Comment: 10,000 total imports per project might still be a constraint for the OP. In this case, he can has at most ~20 tables.